# Can't connect to mysql server with mysql_real_connect()

Tags: c++, mysql

I can't connect to MySQL remote server with this code:

```
MYSQL conn;
bool con_to_db()
{
     conn = mysql_init(0);
     conn =mysql_real_connect(conn, host, user, pass, 0, NULL, 0);
     if(conn)
        //cout<<"connection to atestat databse successful "<<endl;
        return true;
     else
       // cout<<"connection problem: "<<mysql_error(conn)<<endl;
       return false;
}

int main()
{
   if(con_to_db())
     cout<<"connection to atestat databse successful "<<endl;
   else 
      cout<<"connection problem: "<<mysql_error(conn)<<endl;
}
```

after running this code there is a message in the console:

> connection failure

Comment: Are you able to connect using another tool from the same machine? This would indicate if the problem is with the code, or with the setup. Is there anything in the console after the "connection failure" text?

Comment: I suggest you compile your code with warnings first, and fix those warnings. Most warnings are actually errors that prevent your code from running correctly.

Comment: @JasonAller after the text "connection failure" nothing appears

Comment: @Ferrybig don't show me warnings in build log

Answer (score 1):

At the first line of your code `MYSQL conn`. This is the prototype for mysql_real_connect:

```
MYSQL * mysql_real_connect(MYSQL * mysql,
                       const char * host,
                       const char * user,
                       const char * passwd,
                       const char * db,
                       unsigned int port,
                       const char * unix_socket,
                       unsigned long flags);
```

`conn` should be a pointer.

Comment: In my project I've declared conn at pointer but don't connect to server

Comment: At local server it's work but at remote server don't connect

Comment: I don't understand why

Comment: It because you missed the fifth parameter - your database name in which you want to connect to.

Comment: what I missed at fifth argument exactly ?

Comment: After your 'pass' parameter, you need to give the name of the database you want to connect to. For example : mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "root", "demo", 0, NULL, 0) , demo is the name of the db.

Comment: aaaaaaaa i understand but I wrote database name in function . At localhost it work but it doesn't connect to my remote server